# jQuery Syntax Confusing

Tags: jquery, syntax, jquery-validate

I have uploaded my code to js bin and got the following errors  I am unsure how to fix them but I think its due to I am trying to use `},` to pass in my id values.

```
Line 7: required: true; --- Expected '}' to match '{' from line 6 and instead saw ';'.
Line 10: required: true; --- Expected '}' to match '{' from line 9 and instead saw ';'.
Line 12: }, --- Expected an identifier and instead saw '}'.
Line 13: errorPlacement: function(error, element) { --- Expected ')' and instead saw ':'.
Line 13: errorPlacement: function(error, element) { --- Missing semicolon.
Line 13: errorPlacement: function(error, element) { --- Missing name in function declaration.
Line 21: }); --- Expected '(end)' and instead saw '}'.

jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    //Home Validation
    $("#quote").validate({
        onfocusout:true,
          rules:{
                companyName:{
                    required: true;
                },
                companyAddress:{
                    required: true;
                },
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if(element.is("textarea")) {
                    error.appendTo(".textareaError");
                }else{
                    error.appendTo(".error");
                }
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: As I reread this question, I think it might be best that you edit it to clearly state the problem at hand so we know what kind of solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the semicolons on lines 7 and 10 and the comma on line 11.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    //Home Validation
    $("#quote").validate({
        onfocusout:true,
          rules:{
                companyName:{
                    required: true
                },
                companyAddress:{
                    required: true
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if(element.is("textarea")) {
                    error.appendTo(".textareaError");
                }else{
                    error.appendTo(".error");
                }
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Does not seem to be working I get no JS or bugs and its loading fine.

Comment: Did my fix make the errors go away? That seemed like what you were asking for. If there's more to it, maybe you should modify your question or post another.